# GraphPlots - Is there a way to have different colors for edges?

Tags: plot, graph, colors, julia

[Given GraphPlots doc](https://how%20to%20color%20specific%20edges%20julia), we have the following available attributes:

```
function gplot{V, T<:Real}(
    G::AbstractGraph{V},
    locs_x::Vector{T}, locs_y::Vector{T};
    nodelabel::Union(Nothing, Vector) = nothing,
    nodelabelc::ComposeColor = colorant"black",
    nodelabelsize::Union(Real, Vector) = 4,
    nodelabeldist::Real = 0,
    nodelabelangleoffset::Real = π/4.0,
    edgelabel::Union(Nothing, Vector) = nothing,
    edgelabelc::ComposeColor = colorant"black",
    edgelabelsize::Union(Real, Vector) = 4,
    edgestrokec::ComposeColor = colorant"lightgray",
    edgelinewidth::Union(Real, Vector) = 1,
    edgelabeldistx::Real = 0,
    edgelabeldisty::Real = 0,
    nodesize::Union(Real, Vector) = 1,
    nodefillc::ComposeColor = colorant"turquoise",
    nodestrokec::ComposeColor = nothing,
    nodestrokelw::Union(Real, Vector) = 0,
    arrowlengthfrac::Real = Graphs.is_directed(G) ? 0.1 : 0.0,
    arrowangleoffset = 20.0/180.0*π)
```

With `edgestrokec` allowing to change edge's color. However, I have two types of edges in my graph and I would like to color them in two different colors. Is it possible?

```
if !plot_backup_edge
    for i in 1:length(hubs)-1
        add_edge!(inst_graph, hubs[i], hubs[i+1])
        ## TODO: Have a first color here for the edges
    end
    add_edge!(inst_graph, hubs[1], hubs[end])
end
if plot_backup_edge
    for i in 2:length(hubs)-1
        add_edge!(inst_graph, hubs[i-1], hubs[i+1])
        ## TODO: Have a second color here for the edges
    end
    add_edge!(inst_graph, hubs[end-1], hubs[2])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `edgestrokec`:

```
using Colors
G = Graph(8,12)
gplot(G;edgestrokec =rand([colorant"red", colorant"green", colorant"blue"],12))
```

[image]